# Gaussian curvature of Mobius Strip.

Tags: differential-geometry

I read about differential geometry of curves (by do Carmo) and I had seen that to find the Gaussian curvature, I will need a second fundamental form (which means I need an orientable surface, or else I cannot define the unitary normal vector field on it.) But I also know Gaussian curvature is an intrinsic property which means it can be expressed in terms of first fundamental form. As I know, a Mobius strip is not an orientable surface. So, how do I calculate the Gaussian curvature of a Mobius Strip?

Comment: Gaussian curvature does not depend on your choice of outward unit normal. Why?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the metrics you put on the mobius strip. If you see it as embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ with some function, then it has an induced metric.
Locally it is orientable and you can compute the curvature as it is a local calculation.

If you see it as the quotient of the square with reverse identification of two sides, then it is a flat riemannian manifold, with zero curvature.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot I can look the things locally !

Answer (score 1):

I hope **Dldier_**'s answers your doubts, so let me address one problem implicitly mentioned in your question:

1. As mentioned by **Dldier_**, curvature is a local thing, so one can just consider a smaller part of the Mobius strip, which is orientable.
2. If you choose the orientation, you have a unit normal field $\vec{n}$ (compatible with the orientation) and you probably consider the second fundamental form as the real-valued function $$ A_p(u,v) = -\langle \nabla_{u} \vec{n}, v \rangle_p. $$ A change in orientation results in changing the sign of $\vec{n}$ and hence also of $A$. But not of the curvature! This could suggest that the sign convention was artificial in the first place.
3. Instead, one can define the second fundamental as vector-valued, not real-valued: $$ A_p(u,v) = -\langle \nabla_{u} \vec{n}, v \rangle_p \vec{n}_p. $$ This has its advantages:

   - by definition, $A$ does not depend on the chosen orientation;
   - even better, the orientation is not involved at all! you can define $A$ also for non-orientable surfaces;
   - defining $A$ this way, it is easier to grasp the definition of $A$ for submanifolds of arbitrary codimension.